# c# List.Contain(List) not returning true for containing list

Tags: list, c#-4.0, generics, contains, generic-list

I have a parent list as follows.

```
IList<List<int>> parentList = new List<List<int>>();
parentList.Add(new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 });
parentList.Add(new List<int> { 3, 4, 5 });
parentList.Add(new List<int> { 6, 7, 8 });
parentList.Add(new List<int> { 0, 4, 8 });
parentList.Add(new List<int> { 2, 4, 6 });
parentList.Add(new List<int> { 0, 3, 6 });
parentList.Add(new List<int> { 1, 4, 7 });
parentList.Add(new List<int> { 2, 5, 8 });
```

AS a part of my program I am generating a list

```
List<int> listToFind = new List<int>{1, 4, 7};
```

When I try to execute the following, it returns false although it should return true. Am I doing somthing wrong here?

```
parentList.Contains(listToFind);
```

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jankajg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the lists, use `SequenceEqual` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx))

In your case, you can combine it with `Any`:

```
var containsListToFind = parentList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(listToFind));
```

`Contains` won't work because it uses the default `.Equals` method of the objects in the list.  For `List<T>`, that is a reference comparison, not a value comparision.  Since `listToFind` is a different *object* than the one in `parentList`, the references are different and `Contains` won't find anything.

Comment: thanks elmugrat. I was thinking in the same line but did not know about sequenceEqual.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
parentList.Where(pl => listToFind.All(pl.Contains(lf)));
```

Comment: this might work. but the solution provided by @elmugrat was exactly what i was looking for